# How can I configure celery to run on startup of nginx?

Tags: python, nginx, celery, systemd

I have celery running locally by just running `celery -A proj -l info` (although I don't even know if I should be using this command in production), and I want to get celery running on my production web server every time nginx starts. The init system is systemd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a service file like this `celery.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=celery service
After=network.target

[Service]
PIDFile=/run/celery/pid
User=celery
Group=celery
RuntimeDirectory=/path/to/project
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/project
ExecStart=celery -A proj -l info
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID
Restart=on-abort
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Move the file to `/etc/systemd/system/` and next time your restart server, celery will be started by systemd on boot.