# Celery daemonization: "Runtime directory is not valid" for my /etc/systemd/system/celery.service

Tags: nginx, celery, systemd

Here is my /etc/systemd/system/celery.service

```
[Unit]
Description=celery service
After=network.target

[Service]
PIDFile=/run/celery/pid
User=celery
Group=celery
RuntimeDirectory=/home/mike/movingcollage
WorkingDirectory=/home/mike/movingcollage
ExecStart=celery -A movingcollage -l info
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID
Restart=on-abort
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`/home/mike/movingcollage` is a valid directory that works fine elsewhere. where am I going wrong? I am taking advice from this page:

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html#service-file-celery-service

and this answer:

[How can I configure celery to run on startup of nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49377865/how-can-i-configure-celery-to-run-on-startup-of-nginx)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

`RuntimeDirectory` is the name of the directory you want systemd to create under `/run/` for you.

As directory names cannot contain a slash, you are getting the error about the option being invalid.

For your specific use-case, I don't think you want to specify `RuntimeDirectory` at all (does your Celery expect/look for a directory under `/run/`?)

Comment: Not setting a RuntimeDirectory gives me "Executable path is not absolute"

Comment: I just realised you have `PIDFile` under run, so your `RuntimeDirectory` should be 'celery'

Comment: @MikeJohnson that's because it (termporarily) solves your issue; and you're running into the next error. Which is indeed that your ExecStart is not an absolute path! You need to tell it exactly where the `celery` executable is.

Comment: I changed my `RuntimeDirectory=celery` and I am getting: "Service has no ExecStart= setting" (`ExecStart` is the same as it has been)